# Why I am getting this error in reading csv file in jupyter

Tags: python, csv, deep-learning

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\deban\OneDrive\Desktop\spam.csv")
df.head()
```

[Deatils of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huTYQ.png)

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/deban/OneDrive/Desktop/spam.csv', engine='python')
df.head()
```

or this:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/deban/OneDrive/Desktop/spam.csv', encoding='utf-8')
df.head()
```